# Iterating Rows while comparing dates gives the same result each time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I am iterating through column showing the due dates of invoices. I have also create a variable storing the date of Sunday of the current week.

I am trying to create a new row to show if the `due_date` is smaller than this week's `sunday`, I should pay the invoice.

However, when I run the code, the Status column only shows the value Pay.

My code is as below:

```
for index, row in df_320.iterrows():
    if due_date[index] < sunday:    
        df_320['Status'] = "Pay"
    elif due_date[index] >= sunday:
        df_320['Status'] = "Skip"
```

I have tried the below code to see if all the conditions show True but it also shows False values.

```
for index, row in df_320.iterrows():
   print(due_date[index] < sunday)
```

I would appreciate if you can point out what Im doing wrong.

DATEFRAME EXAMPLE:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8Nb4.png)

Comment: A statement like `df_320['Status'] = "Pay"` will set the *entire* `Status` column to have a value of `"Pay"`.  You are always changing the whole column at once.  You probably want something like [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed that due_date and Sunday are datetime / date objects? You need to parse the date strings into objects to perform comparisons between them. Link to datetime docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Also you seem to modify the same structure you are iterating (df_320), same column regardless of your position, are you sure this is what you want to do? I'm guessing you want to change 'row' instead?

Comment: Yes they are bot datetime objects. When I iterate without a loop and print the condition, It works. True for due_date[index] smaller than sunday and False for due_date[index] equal or bigger than sunday. My loop may be the problem but I am not sure.